# Displaying a `std::map`

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, std

Declared a map early on:

```
map<char*,char*>    rtable; // used to store routing information
```

Now I'm attempting to display the contents of the map:

```
void Routes::viewroutes(){
    typedef map<char*, char*>::const_iterator iter;
    for (iter=rtable.begin(); iter != rtable.end(); ++iter) {
        cout << iter->second << " " << iter->first << endl;
    }
}
```

Receiving the error "expected primary-expression before '!=' token and for '->' token. Can't seem to understand the error I'm making here. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that a `char*` as a map key does not do what most beginners would expect. The default comparison, by which a `std::map<char*,char*>` is sorted, will sort keys __according to their address, not according to their values__. Whether `"blah"` and `"blah"` compare equal, depends on whether the compiler folds identical string literals - an optimization setting for many compilers. Usually you want to use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Comment: That and the memory issues.  char* is an abomination.

Comment: sbi -- I appreciate the comment. I was just beginning to try and figure out why my map wasn't sorting as expected.

Comment: (Please properly @address when you reply in comments, otherwise it won't show up in our responses and we never see your replies.) Just use `std::string` for all string-related stuff and do away with C's character arrays. It's much easier, far less error-prone, it rarely ever causes significant performance losses, and even if it does, you can still fall back to character arrays punctually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iter` is a type in your code. Should be a variable.

```
typedef map<char*,char*> my_map_t;  // alias for a specialized map

// declare a variable of needed type
my_map_t    rtable;

// declare iter of type my_map_t::const_iterator
for (my_map_t::const_iterator iter=rtable.begin(); iter != rtable.end(); ++iter) {
    cout << iter->second << " " << iter->first << endl;
}
// scope of the iter variable will be limited to the loop above
```

Comment: preserving the typedef is just a little convoluted, don't you think?

Comment: it is not very handy to write a full type of the iterator each time. typedef's make life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the typedef.  You're not declaring a variable with that statement, you're defining a type and then assigning to it.  That's what the error is.

Comment: What is the point of the typedef then? It appears in a sample code I have.

Comment: The typedef can save you some typing but not where you have it.  If you want to use it, define it where you declare your map.  But give it a name that looks like a type, not a variable.  Something like:

typedef map<char*,char*>::const_iterator MapCIter;

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable of type `iter`:

```
void Routes::viewroutes(){
    typedef map<char*, char*>::const_iterator iter;
    for (iter i =rtable.begin(); i != rtable.end(); ++i) {
        cout << i->second << " " << i->first << endl;
    }
}
```

---

Just for fun :), you can use the following functions which I wrote to stream the contents of a map or a multimap to any standard stream whether it is the standard output, a file stream. It deals with all types of streams like cout or wcout for example:

```
    template <class Container, class Stream>
    Stream& printPairValueContainer(Stream& outputstream, const Container& container)
    {
        typename Container::const_iterator beg = container.begin();

        outputstream << "[";

        while(beg != container.end())
        {
            outputstream << " " << "<" << beg->first << " , " << beg->second << ">";
            beg++;
        }

        outputstream << " ]";

        return outputstream;
    }

template
    < class Key, class Value
    , template<class KeyType, class ValueType, class Traits = std::less<KeyType>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const KeyType, ValueType> > > 
    class Container
    , class Stream
    >
Stream& operator<<(Stream& outputstream, const Container<Key, Value>& container)
{
    return printPairValueContainer(outputstream, container);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I always access my map iterators like so (*iter).first and (*iter).second.

Comment: Why?  Got something against the -> operator?

Comment: Ouch, people really don't like my answer.  :-) 
No, no, I don't have anything against operator->().  That's just how I learned it way back in the day, and I've just never changed.  Creature of habit and all that.